# related author post thumbnail shows post thumbnail

Tags: posts, post-thumbnails, thumbnails

using the code below to show 4 related posts from author

```
<?php global $authordata, $post; ?>
<?php $authors_posts = get_posts( array( 'author' => $authordata->ID, 'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ), 'posts_per_page' => 4 ) ); ?>

<?php foreach ( $authors_posts as $authors_post ) { ?>

<div class="uk-width-medium-1-4">
<a href="<?php the_permalink($authors_post->ID) ?>">
<?php the_post_thumbnail($authors_post->ID); ?>
</a>
</div>

<?php } ?>
```

Problem is, permalinks work fine, but the thumbnail is on all 4 related links the same as the thumb on the post itself. Which is set as featured image on the post I want to set the related posts. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem may be that [`the_post_thumbnail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/) doesn't accept an ID as a parameter. Instead you should use [`get_the_post_thumbnail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/) which does accept an ID as a parameter:

```
 <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($authors_post->ID); ?>
```

Comment: I tried it before but only as `<?php get_the_post_thumbnail($authors_post->ID); ?>` and didn't realise I needed to echo this. Thanks Stephen, works like a charm!